# 'Dose of one's own medicine'?

Tags: idioms

So, I know 'dose of your own medicine' is an older version of 'taste of your own medicine'; but which one is widely used nowadays? Are both of them correct, or did people stop saying 'dose of your own medicine'?

Comment: "Taste" only recently (circa 1970) become more common:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dose+of+his+own+medicine%2Ctaste+of+his+own+medicine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdose%20of%20his%20own%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaste%20of%20his%20own%20medicine%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

I had not heard 'dose of your own medicine' but I can believe it was used. Taste of your own medicine is common nowadays. I think 'taste' may have been more common since the taste is usually the worst part of medicine.

Comment: Can you support any of this with data?